# Slow runtime when converting HDF5 file datasets into a three -dimensional numpy array in Python

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5

I have a HDF5 file with three datasets; one containing names and the other two containing associated values. The datasets are large with almost 100,000,000 elements each. I'd like to print the top 300 name-value pairs to a file in tab-delimited format, however, I'm having an issue with implementing my solution.

I want to combine the three datasets into a three-dimensional numpy array, so that I can sort the values by the second column and pull out the top 300 rows. However, my program doesn't appear to be able to construct the three-dimensional numpy array, at least not in a reasonable runtime. My code is seen below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Importing modules.
import h5py
import numpy as np

# Creating path for HDF5 file.
HDF5_PATH = ('/path/to/hdf5_file.hdf5')

# Creating path for outfile.
OUTFILE_PATH = ('/path/to/outfile.tsv')

# Loading HDF5 file.
hdf5_file = h5py.File(HDF5_PATH, 'r')

# Getting 3D array of datasets.
print('Building array')
hdf5_arr = np.array([hdf5_file['col_1'], hdf5_file['col_2'], hdf5_file['col_3']])

# Getting top 300 rows by second column.
print('Getting top 300 values')
top_300_arr = hdf5_arr[np.argpartition(hdf5_arr, axis=1)]

# Printing top 300 rows.
print('Printing top 300 values')
    with open(OUTFILE_PATH, 'a') as outfile:
        np.savetxt(outfile, top_300_arr, delimiter="\t", fmt='%s')
```

I've added print statements to monitor progress, and currently, my code prints out `Building array` and doesn't appear to progress for at least an hour. That would mean that my issues is with the line `hdf5_arr = np.array([hdf5_file['col_1'], hdf5_file['col_2'], hdf5_file['col_3']])`. Is there any way I can improve my code so that it can work in a suitable runtime?

Comment: What's the time for `x=hdf5_file['col_1'][...]`?  That is, simply loading one dataset.

Comment: According to `timeit.default_timer()`, only 1.6437843441963196e-06 seconds. That must mean that there's something wring with how I'm building my array right?

Comment: But if I do `x = np.array(hdf5_file['col_1'])`, it's 20.615581781603396, and `x = np.array([hdf5_file['col_1'], hdf5_file['col_1']])` doesn't seem like it will complete in a suitable runtime.

Comment: I'd first load the 3 arrays.  What's the shape and dtype of each?  `np.array` loads them and then concatenates on a new initial axis.  You might want to delay that until after selecting the top 300.

Comment: How about RAM usage? (Are you running out of physical RAM)? Shape and Chunkshape of your dataset? Insufficent chunk-cache can lead even to slow sequential reading for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48446301/4045774

Comment: Provided it fits all easily in memory, `hdf5_arr = np.array([hdf5_file['col_1'][:], hdf5_file['col_2'][:], hdf5_file['col_3'][:]])` will load the data as NumPy arrays directly and *then* process them. In some situations, indexing directly h5py datasets is slow and it is better to load the data in RAM.