# Fast and efficient way of serializing and retrieving a large number of numpy arrays from HDF5 file

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py, numpy-ndarray

I have a huge list of numpy arrays, specifically `113287`, where each array is of shape `36 x 2048`. In terms of memory, this amounts to *32 Gigabytes*.

As of now, I have serialized these arrays as a giant HDF5 file. Now, the problem is that retrieving individual arrays from this hdf5 file takes excruciatingly long time (north of 10 mins) for each access.

How can I speed this up? This is very important for my implementation since I have to index into this list *several thousand times* for feeding into Deep Neural Networks.

Here's how I index into hdf5 file:

```
In [1]: import h5py
In [2]: hf = h5py.File('train_ids.hdf5', 'r')

In [5]: list(hf.keys())[0]
Out[5]: 'img_feats'

In [6]: group_key = list(hf.keys())[0]

In [7]: hf[group_key]
Out[7]: <HDF5 dataset "img_feats": shape (113287, 36, 2048), type "<f4">


# this is where it takes very very long time
In [8]: list(hf[group_key])[-1].shape
Out[8]: (36, 2048)
```

Any ideas where I can speed things up? Is there any other way of serializing these arrays for faster access?

Note: I'm using a Python list since I want the order to be preserved (i.e. to retrieve in the same order as I put it when I created the hdf5 file)

Comment: You can put your list in a big 3d array, in which case [memory mapping](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) might help. I have no idea about practical implications and speed, hence only a comment.

Comment: You are using a chunked dataset. In most cases you need to adapt the chunk-cache size to get resonable performance. It would be also good to adapt the chunksize to your needs. It shouldn't be a problem to get a few hundret MB/s if your sequential disk IO-Speed is fast enough.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48405220/4045774

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `Out[7]`, "img_feats" is a large 3d array.  (113287, 36, 2048) shape.

Define `ds` as the dataset (doesn't load anything):

```
ds = hf[group_key]

x = ds[0]    # should be a (36, 2048) array

arr = ds[:]   # should load the whole dataset into memory.
arr = ds[:n]   # load a subset, slice
```

According to [h5py-reading-writing-data](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/dataset.html#reading-writing-data) :

> HDF5 datasets re-use the NumPy slicing syntax to read and write to the file. Slice specifications are translated directly to HDF5 “hyperslab” selections, and are a **fast and efficient way to access data** in the file.

I don't see any point in wrapping that in `list()`; that is, in splitting the 3d array in a list of 113287 2d arrays.  There's a clean mapping between 3d datasets on the HDF5 file and `numpy` arrays.

[h5py-fancy-indexing](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/dataset.html#fancy-indexing) warns that fancy indexing of a dataset is slower.  That is, seeking to load, say [1, 1000, 3000, 6000] subarrays of that large dataset.

You might want to experiment with writing and reading some smaller datasets if working with this large one is too confusing.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to put each sample into its own group and index directly into those. I am thinking the conversion takes long because it tries to load the entire data set into a list  (which it has to read from disk). Re-organizing the h5 file such that

- group

  - sample

    - 36 x 2048
      may help in indexing speed.