# Slicing a Large Numpy Array into Individual Arrays

Tags: python, numpy, h5py, hdf

I have a (30000, 25, 25) dimension hdf file and have already converted it into a numpy array with the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

hf = h5py.File('data.h5', 'r')
n1 = np.array(hf["image"][:]) 
x = n1[0:625:30000]
print(x)
```

In hdfview, after changing its dimensions, I was able to create 30000 individual 25 X 25 arrays. However, with the code above, I am only able to open the first array. The code below is able to show the first array:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

hf = h5py.File('data.h5', 'r')
n1 = np.array(hf["image"][:]) 
x[0] = n1[0:625:30000]
print(x)
```

When I change `x[0]` to `x[1]` or anything higher it says - "index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1." Is there a solution to output 30000 of these 25 X 25 arrays demonstrated in hdfview?

Comment: can you post the `shape` of `n1`?

Comment: @brainfuck4d, I think the first line means the 'image' dataset is 3d: (30000, 25,25).  A file itself doesn't have a shape.

Answer (score 0):

```
n1 = hf["image"][:]
```

is enough.  It is a numpy array.  No need to wrap it in `np.array(...)` again.

`x = n1[0:625:30000]` doesn't make sense.  In Python, slicing is `[start:stop:step]`.

`x = n1[::625]` will return a subset, ever 625th element (on the first dimension).

'x = n1[0]`is the first (25,25) block (or image).`x = n1[1]` the second.

In `numpy` indexing `n1[0]` is the equivalent of `n1[0, :, :]`, selecting an item on the 1st dimension.

I have a feeling you've jumped into processing these images (for machine learning or something like that), without learning much `python` or `numpy`.  If you are just following a tutorial that might work, but you'll get lost if you stray off that guided path.

This other `h5py` SO post from the same time as your first is relevant:

[Efficient way of serializing and retrieving a large number of numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53026032/efficient-way-of-serializing-and-retrieving-a-large-number-of-numpy-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, it looks like I just over complicated it by adding unnecessary slicing. I am slightly unfamiliar with numpy so I'll learn more about it to avoid problems. Thank you all once again for you time.