# Compressing HDF5 Files without HDF5 Compression Filters

Tags: python, numpy, compression, hdf5, h5py

Which compression algorithms are typically used when compressing HDF5 file that were created without applying any HDF5 compression filters?

My HDF5 files are created with `h5py` in Python 3.8 and contain N-dimensional numpy arrays of 32-bit floats ranging between -1.0 and 1.0 shapes similar to `(1000000,10,200)` . Data is being read as `(1,10,200)` arrays in a random pattern. Chunking the HDF5 datasets appear to make non-continuous/random reading/selection significantly slower, thus chunking was disabled which prevented the use of HDF5 compression filters.

Comment: What benchmarks have you performed to verify that the chunking is actually impacting I/O performance? If it is, is it actually significant enough to warrant requiring contiguous data over chunked?

Your compression method will largely depend on the nature of the underlying data. Can you provide more details about it?

Comment: @esilk No comprehensive benchmarks were performed. Current dataset is a (1000000,10,200) numpy array containing float32 which is being read (1,10,200) at a time in a random pattern. Setting the chunk size to (1,10,200) made the random reads 5-10X slower. Updated question with these details

Comment: I should clarify what I meant about the nature of the data -- I don't just mean its shape and representation. I assume the data isn't just toy data, and is instead measurements of some phenomena. Are there well known methods for compressing it within the domain (JPEG for images, FLAC for audio, etc.)? If not, are there patterns/structures in the data that can be exploited to reduce the representation?

Comment: @esilk Thanks, the data has no domain specific compressions that I know of. The arrays contain data that have been calculated off the original measurement data. The original data has been excluded from this dataset.

Comment: I'm not sure I can make many suggestions, then. Compression tends to be specific to the nature of the data, and trying arbitrary techniques may result in no major gains (or even losses): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression#Limitations

Comment: There is a nice discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48405220/10462884. See comments about using `h5py_cache`. More on `h5py_cache` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44961222/10462884. Have you considered PyTables (aka tables module)? They have an excellent discussion on optimization, chunking, compression algorithms here: https://www.pytables.org/usersguide/optimization.html. It's worth a read.

Comment: Add an example what you have tried regarding chunking and how you write the dataset (it may be fragmented on a HDD).  Is the access pattern really completely random or only "somehow" random?